# Combobox not drawn correctly

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, combobox, user-controls

I'm busy writing a usercontrol in C# but when I display it, the combobox is not drawn correctly as can be seen below:

[image: Combobox]

However when I hover with my mouse over the combobox, it redraws correctly. Does anybody have an idea why this happens and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure I can tell from the picture exactly what sort of "wrong" you mean.  That it looks overlapped, or that the button is odd?

Comment: I see four comboboxes with different looks. Also: Tell us all about the related events you code, like Paint, Enter, MouseOver etc..

Comment: @DonBoitnott I mean that the button is odd. TaW there are only two comboboxes but apparently they do not scale well. I have no special events defined except  "roleComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged".